# "abc" is not a registered tag library. must be one of: "efg" | django

Tags: python, django, templates, filter, tags

I was actually trying to find a way to sort  a queryset in my template and saw that we can create our custom filter and use it.

let's not to mention the function I put into my tag but I created the tag in the same directory as all other tags...

I created my tag name `sort_tags.py` under `templatetags`
*weird I cannot upload image, was going to show my directories`
Anyways, that's where all other tags are.

I got this piece of code and want to try it..so I paste it into my `sort_tags.py`

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def sort_by(queryset, order):
    return queryset.order_by(order)
```

then in my `template.html` I used `{% load sort_tags %}` also, there are other tags being loaded too.

Then when I load the page...`is not a registered tag library. must be one of` shows up.  in the list of MUST BE, I see all the tags in the same directory as me.

I tried something like `filter_function`, `register_filter('sort_by',sort_by)`
or something similar, found a few different ways, so I tried them all and none of them work.

Does anyone has any idea what might be wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this inside a template (which is a bit wrong actually), you should be using the `regroup` tag — https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

But actually, you should move the logic to the view as much as possible.